# Listar nombre de funciones clases y métodos de un archivo de Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones

Conocen alguna extension o ide que muestre en fomato de lista, arbol o jerarquia las funciones, clases y metodos de un archivo de Python?

Por ejemplo si necesitara listar estos objetos de un submodulo de matplotlib (que son archivos con bastantes líneas de código) como podria hacerlo? VS Code señala en una parte la raiz y el archivo en el que me encuentro y si me posiciono en una clase el muestra como una lista pero es muy poco intuitiva, de necesitar hacerlo con toda la libreria seria bastante tedioso. Matplotlib detalla todo eso en la documentación pero como hacerlo en un conjunto de archivos sin documentación?

He encontrado ciertas extensiones que hacen algo similar pero con directorios

PD: solo busco en tal caso nombres no necesariamente su definición

Ejemplo

- funcion_a
- clase_aaa

  - metodo_x
  - metodo_y
- clase_bbb
- otra funcion

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este codigo lista todas las clases y funciones no internas (ej:`__init__` NO es agregado al listado) del modulo `os`.
No es una extensión o ide, y creo que no es lo que esperas, ya que no analiza archivos como tal, pero espero que sirva igualmente.

```
import os

def listado(modulo):
    tree = ""

    for nombre in dir(modulo):
        objeto = getattr(modulo, nombre)
        
        if(callable(objeto)):
            if(isinstance(objeto, type)):
                tree += "class "+nombre+"\n"
                tree += "\n".join("    -"+metodo for metodo in dir(objeto) if(callable(getattr(objeto, metodo)) and metodo[:2]+metodo[-2:] != "____"))
                tree += "\n"
            else:
                tree += "def "+nombre+"\n"

    return tree

print(listado(os))
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias compañero!